# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::binParam()

Tags: php

[Re-editado]

Ya solucione el problema anterior, ahora para probar el login me salta otro error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::binParam() in C:\xampp\htdocs\seraph\login.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\seraph\login.php on line 13

aqui esta la parte del php del login:

```
<?php 

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header('Location: /seraph');
}

require 'database.php';

if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, email, password FROM user WHERE email=:email');
    $records->binParam(':email',$_POST['email']);
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $message = "";

    if (count($result) > 0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['password'])) {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results['id'];
        header('Location: /seraph');
    } else {
        $message = "No coninciden";
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: No te hartes, no sirve de nada. Lee detenidamente el mensaje de error: *`Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'seraph_database.users' doesn't exist`*. Te está diciendo claramente que la tabla `users` no existe en la base de datos `seraph_database`, por tanto, crea esa tabla o conecta a la base de datos que posee la tabla `users` con la que quieres trabajar.

Comment: Ya funciona pero ahora cuando intento prpbar el login me da este error ahora: 

"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::binParam() in C:\xampp\htdocs\seraph\login.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\seraph\login.php on line 13"

Comment: Falta una `d`, es **`bindParam()`** no `binParam()`.

Comment: Gracias ya lo he solucionado y funciona a la perfección.